# Why does n times the empty list in python return the empty list instead of zero or n or n empty lists?

Tags: python, list, default-value

I was doing a udacity exercise that required me to multiply all elements of a list together.  I was able to do it using a simple loop.  I know that there are built in functions to do this, but I wanted to do the exercise as suggested in order to learn the material.

Here's the code:

```
def product_list(myList):
    product = 1
    for item in myList:
        product = product * item
    return product
```

For the empty list, this returned:

```
>>>1
```

which was the function's default return value.

I also noticed in the python interpreter that:

```
4 * []
>>> []
```

However

```
4 * [1, 2, 3]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

What's the logic behind this behavior?

Comment: simply think wt you will get when you multiply to null??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying a list causes it to repeat the *contents*. An empty list has no contents to repeat.

From the [*Sequences Types* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

> `s * n`, `n * s`
>   `n` shallow copies of `s` concatenated

If you wanted to produce a new list *containing* the referenced list repeatedly, put it in another list first:

```
>>> [[]] * 4
[[], [], [], []]
```

but take into account that that creates 4 *references*, all pointing to the same nested list. Manipulations to that list are then shared:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [a] * 4
>>> b
[[], [], [], []]
>>> a.append('foo')
>>> b
[['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo']]
```

If you need separate copies, use a list comprehension and create copies explicitly:

```
[lstobj[:] for _ in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[]
```

The above expression represents an empty list, in other words its a list that contains nothing. The multiplication expression works by multiplying the sequence of items that is stored in the list by a value specified :

```
[1,2,3] * 2
[1,2,3,1,2,3] # output
```

Multiplying "nothing" by any number will give you "nothing".